# Use unclassified texts to improve BERT and RNN GRUN token classification model

Tags: rnn, bert, gru

I have a training (gold) labelled dataset than consists of 10000 sentences. The task is to create a model that classifies correctly unseen data with B-I-O tags.

I have used a BERT and a GRU RNN model.

Now, I also have millions of sentences from the same field (law) but these have no label. I have tried to produce silver labels and re train the models on the full dataset but the results were not great. How can I use these unclassified data to improve a) a BERT model and b) the GRU model? Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: You can pretrain BERT and the GRU with your unlabeled data and then fine-tune them with the labeled data.